# How do I create a mock instance inside of a method in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

So here is a simplified version of my classes.  I have two classes that implement a service interface.  One is my actual implementation and one is my mock.
I need to create X number of new instances of this service class inside of my Worker class.

How do I tell my Worker class which IService I want to use?
Is mocking up the Worker class the only route to go?  Is there a better route?

**Edit:**
So after reading some of the responses, I feel that I did not accurately convey my situation.  I oversimplified to the point of hindering.  Anyways I added more code that may help explain what I have going on.

I changed the original `Worker` class to be `Manager` and have a child list of `Workers`.  The list of workers is created from the `Manager` class and I construct them using the `IService` which I would like to pass a Concrete OR Mock implementation.  I then will kick off the Workers to do something involving `IService` and a variable that I provide it.  (In this case it's just an integer, but in real life it's a class).

```
public interface IService
{
    int a { get; set; }
}

public class Concrete : IService
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    float x;

    public Concrete(int A)
    {
        a = A;
        x = 0.500F;
    }
}

public class Mock : IService
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    float x;

    public Mock(int A)
    {
        a = A;
        x = 0.750F;
    }
}

public class Manager
{
    List<Worker> Workers = new List<Worker>();

    void CreateList() 
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            Worker w = new Worker(new IService(i)); //<-- Need help here!
            theList.Add(w);
        }

        KickOffWorkesAsync();
    }

    void KickOffWorkesAsync()
    {
        // process the workers async
    }

}

public class Worker
{
    IService _iService;

    public Worker(IService _iSer)
    {
        _iService = _iSer;
    }

    void DoSomething() 
    {
        //do work with _iService
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: consider not inventing your own mocking framework. Use existing one like [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks for the note.  I would agree that I would be farther ahead to use an existing mocking framework.  I'm still new to mocking out classes and unit testing them and want to learn the basics before I have something do it all for me.  Maybe not the best reason, but I'm just trying to get a good foundation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative is to give the worker a factory method that will create the service:

```
public class Worker
{
    private Func<int, IService> createService;

    public Worker(Func<int, IService> createService)
    {
        this.createService = createService;
    }
```

Then the worker can do:

```
void DoSomething() 
{
    var theList = new List<IService>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        IService s = createService(i); // Invoke the provided factory method
        theList.Add(s);
    }

    // do something with the list...
}
```

and the unit test can create the worker like so:

```
public void SomeTestMethod()
{
    var worker = new Worker(CreateMockService);
}

private IService CreateMockService(int arg)
{
    return new Mock(arg);
}
```

The production code would provide a factory method creating real services.

Answer (score 2):

This is where [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) comes in handy. You'll need to design your classes to get their dependencies from outside instead of creating them yourself.

Something like:

```
public class Worker
{
  public Worker(IService service) 
  {
    this.service = service;
  }

  public void DoSomething()
  {
    DoSomethingWith(service);
  }
}
```

Then in your tests, you could create a `Worker` instance injected with a mock service, whereas in production code you'll use a real service.

When using Dependency Injection, it helps to use a DI Container (also sometimes called an Inversion of Control Container), to wire up the dependent services correctly instead of manually creating the dependency graph. Some common DI Containers for .NET include [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/), [StructureMap](http://docs.structuremap.net/), [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/), and Microsoft's [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/).

If you've never used DI before, it's quite a paradigm shift, but it's essentially a simple change that can do wonders to the design of your code (for many reasons, not just for testing).

Comment: +1. Note that based on OP's code some sort of factory would be more appropriate. I.e. `Func<IService> serviceCreator` as dependency.

Comment: I believe OP's code is simplified for the sake of the question, and in general I think pointing a developer towards the DI paradigm without equipping them with a DI container would just make them replace one kind of messy code with another.

Comment: @Avish Thank you for your response, I clarified my code above and was wondering if this changes your response.  I'm leaning towards the `Func` solution which @Alexei Levenkov and @user3544950 mentioned.

Comment: It's basically the same, except that now your `Manager` doesn't depend on the `IService` itself but on some `IServiceFactory` which it then uses to initialize each worker with a service instance. You can represent this factory with a `Func<IWorker>`, just as you can represent any single-method interface with a functional delegate type. Conceptually you're still doing the same thing, which is injecting the dependency from outside (using the constructor). Except you're representing the dependency in a way that's harder to understand, extend or intercept.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question as simple as I can.

```
  void DoSomething() 
  {
      var theList = new List<IService>();
      for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
      {
          //use this
          IService s = new Concrete(i); 
          //or this
          //IService s = new new Mock(i);
          theList.Add(s);
      }

      // do something with the list...
  }
```

But the better way is to use some type of dependency injection or factory (like the other answer explains), so you could specify either in a config file, or in your app startup, what `IService` you want to use.